# get the exact position of text from image in tesseract

Tags: iphone, tesseract

Using GetHOCRText(0) method in tesseract I'm able to retrieve the text in html and on presenting the html in webview i'm able get the text but the postion of text in image is different from the output. Any idea is highly helpful.

```
 tesseract->SetInputName("word");
tesseract->SetOutputName("xyz");
tesseract->Recognize(NULL);


char *utf8Text=tesseract->GetHOCRText(0);
```

[image: This the image i'm using for tesseract]

and output image[image]

Comment: have you got any success with position recognition?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the hocr output, you should have a tag for each word. These tags should have class="ocrx_word" and name="bbox x1 y1 x2 y2" where the x and y are the top left and bottom right corner of the bounding box around the word. I don't think it's possible to automatically use this information to format a text document - would require translating pixel differences to number of tabs/spaces. But, you should be able to render text in the given location.

Answer (score 1):

`GetBoxText()` method will return exact position of each characters in an array.

```
char *boxtext = _tesseract->GetBoxText(0);
NSString* aBoxText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:boxtext];
```

Comment: How to do this with Swift ?!