# How to get text position using Tesseract OCR API in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am doing character recognition in ID cards in `opencv-2.x` using `C++`. I tried `Tesseract OCR`, but it didn't give me better results than my own `neural network` training and all. Although, I am still struggling with segmentation of characters. I was wondering if it is possible to get the character or word position from `Tesseract OCR Api` in `C++` and use my `neural network` for prediction. Any suggestions?

**Simply, I need bounding box of each character in ID using Tesseract.**

Comment: Can you post a sample image of the text??

Comment: actually, NO. Those are IDs, can't be shared!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278982/get-the-exact-position-of-text-from-image-in-tesseract check this might help If you want to detect the text location with tessearct .

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the position of each word using the [run](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html#a59190c76d19dfcac40fe011ff16c18d9) function:

```
virtual void cv::text::OCRTesseract::run(Mat& image, 
                                         std::string& output_text, 
                                         std::vector<Rect>* component_rects = NULL, 
                                         std::vector<std::string>* component_texts = NULL, 
                                         std::vector<float>* component_confidences = NULL, 
                                         int component_level = 0);
```

where `component_rects` will provide a list of Rects for the individual text elements found, and `component_level = OCR_LEVEL_WORD` will find single words.

Comment: Sorry for not informing. I am not using `opencv-3.x`, I am using `opencv-2.9.x`. And I am quite sure there is no `OCRTesseract` in my verson of `opencv`.

Comment: Ok, that's an information you should've included.. Don't worry about this, just update your question to be more clear.  I've done that for a project some times ago... I'll update my answer tomorrow if you didn't found your answer yet. @SuJit

Comment: Thanks! I am still looking for the solution.

Comment: Please have a look at the way [OpenCV uses tesseract internally](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/src/ocr_tesseract.cpp). You'll find out at [line 207](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/src/ocr_tesseract.cpp#L207) that you just need to use `ResultIterator`. Sorry but I can't write a working example right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use HOCR format for your results instead of plain text. I think the argument is -hocr or just hocr. Embedded in the HOCR results (which are returned as XHTML, but it's easy to convert to JSON) are the page coordinates of every word.

Shameless plug, you can also try my online OCR service http://OCRestful.com, which offers OCR as a service via a RESTful API. Just POST your doc and get back JSON with word coordinates and word-by-word confidence scores. There's a permanently-free tier as well as paid plans.

You mentioned your data is sensitive--you can force the document to auto-delete after it's OCR-processed, and you control the lifetime of the extracted OCR data.

Matt